# How to make thousands of queries into less

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complicated SQL problem that I have try to simplify but it is still very very slow. Problem is that it is slow because I run a couple thousand queries to collect all my datas, and my heart tells me there is a way SQL can do this better for me so the query analyzer can find efficiency my own code cannot. I have try to simplify below so I hope it is understandable and I have not made mistake.

I have 2 tables: "operation" and "operationtime".

"Operation" contain 5000 record with a name, number, and so on. An "operation" is 1 action that is being performed by machine in a warehouse, for example "paint box red" or "stamp box with date of assembling"

Every day all operation happen exactly 1 time. Each time operation happen, it become "operationtime" table record. "Time" record has "operation 1521 happened at 2016-01-16 13:45:00 and was 12 seconds for machine 1". There are 10 machine where each operation happen at the same time, so the same operation number and date will have 10 record with different seconds for the time. (Machines are not exactly the same so time are not the same.) So each operation record make 10 operationtime record because there are 10 machine.

5000 operation x 1 time every day x 10 machine = 50,000 record every day in "operationtime" table. We keep 1 year of data so 50,000 x 365 = 18,250,000 record in operationtime.

**That is our situation.**

We are trying to do optimization of our machine and want to see change of machine speed over time for each operation. We change a part of machine, or setting of machine, then run operation next day. I want to show me all operation and for every operation how long eeach machine worked and if that is faster or slow than the same machine-time-operation 1 month ago and 6 month ago. So:

```
Paint box red
Machine 1: 12 seconds (1m 12 seconds, 6m 16 seconds)
Machine 2: 11 seconds (1m 11 seconds, 6m 11 seconds)
Machine 3: 13 seconds (1m 16 seconds, 6m 26 seconds)
Machine 4: 13 seconds (1m 12 seconds, 6m 16 seconds)
```

So you see from that I can see machine 1 is a bit faster, machine 2 has not changed, machine 3 is getting mich better, and machine 4 is doing OK.

**That is what we want.**

**What I am doing right now is slow.** It is this: make query `SELECT operation_id, operation_name FROM operations` to get list of operation for headings in print out. Then for every operation I say this three times: `SELECT machine_id, time_taken FROM operationtime WHERE operation_id = :operation_id AND operation_time = :operation_time` and change `:operation_time` to be newest time, 1 month time and 6 month time. Three readings. operation_id has index. I try add operation_time index as well but that made it very much slower.

I am then putting together result in PHP:

- Run query with newest time.
- Go loop through all result from query to find time for each machine. Run query again with 1 month time.
- Go loop through all result from query to find time for each machine. Run query again with 6 month time.
- Go loop through all result from query to find time for each machine.
- Final result is PHP array of all operation, for each operation 10 machine, and for each machine 3 times.

We have 1000 operation so this become 3000 queries and adding all the PHP looping time. With 18 million rows this is extremely slow. It take a loooong time to run. Our goal is to optimize machine to go from 1000 operation to 10000 operation, but I don't think our current database can do it because it is so slow now and will only get more slow when more operation added.

**What I want is SQL query that can do this work for me** because I hope MySQL can analyze what I am doing and find most efficient way of answering. "Here is list of operation ID, please give me result for every machine for every operation: current time, 1 month time and 6 month time."

If it were perfect I would get column name like "Machine 1", "Today Time", "1m Time", "6m time" but I do not think that is possible. Maybe if I could at least get all answer in one query I could still use PHP to group data into operation and machine.

**I am using MySQL, I am using InnoDB. I have index on operation_id.**

I am so sorry this is a complicated question. I have made it as simple as I can and hope I made no mistake. Thank you for reading. Any suggestion is helpful thank you!

Comment: For a start, you should **join** your tables rather than repeatedly querying within a loop in PHP: `SELECT operation_name, machine_id, time_taken FROM operations JOIN operationtime USING (operation_id) WHERE operation_time = :operation_time`.  Next you should ensure that the `operationtime` table has a *composite* index over `(operation_id, operation_time)`.

Comment: Even better `SELECT * 
FROM operations o 
    JOIN operationtime ot ON o.operation_id=ot.operation_id 
WHERE operation_time = :operation_time
   OR operation_time = :operation_time_month_ago
   OR operation_time = :operation_time_6_month_ago` to get all times for all the 3 dates. You can also add group by and order by to provide necessary aggregation and desired order

Comment: if operation time is always "today" create a view with StanislavL comment. Also as eggyal suggest create a composite index on both operation_id and operation_time

Comment: So is read view of query is faster than running normal query?